# Join() in groovy doesn't wait for threads to finish

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy

I'm expecting the output to be:

```
testing
DONE! 6
```

but it's actually

```
DONE! 5
```

Doesn't join() wait for the thread to finish?

```
Thread[] T = new Thread[3];
int n = 5;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    T[i] = new Thread();
Thread x = new Thread();
T[1].start{
    sleep(500);
    log.info "testing";
}
x.start{
    n++;
}

x.join();
T[1].join();
log.info "DONE! " + n;
```

Comment: You are treading deep waters ;). I get `Done! 6 testing` with `Groovy Version: 2.4.7 JVM: 1.8.0_112 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X`

Comment: nice, at least I know it's not the code. I'm using Groovy inside SoapUI 5.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is your not starting your threads (`T[1]` & `x`).

When you say `T[1].start{..` it does not mean you are starting the `T[1}` thread you are just creating and starting anonymous thread.

**Solution**:

```
T[1] = T[1].start{
    sleep(500);
    log.info "testing";
}
```

**Working Code:**

```
Thread[] T = new Thread[3];
int n = 5;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    T[i] = new Thread();
Thread x = new Thread();
T[1] = T[1].start{
    sleep(500);
    println "testing";
}
x= x.start{
    n++;
}

x.join();
T[1].join();
println "DONE! " + n;
```

Check the doc for [details](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Thread.html#start(groovy.lang.Closure)):